# How to set View.SynchronizeClassView hotkey in Rider?

Tags: rider

Is there a way to set a hotkey for the function corresponding to View.SynchronizeClassView in Visual Studio in Rider?
I would like to know how I can set the View.SynchronizeClassView shortcut like in that image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WETnU.png)

Comment: Please add image description, screenshot could be embedded so there would be no need to click to see the content. The content should be in english too.

Comment: I edited the image and uploaded it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Type Hierarchy` in `Rider` with selected `Class Hierarchy` is an equivalent of `Visual Studio`'s `Class Hierarchy`, then you can easily change the hotkey for synchronizing with current view.
By default it is set to `Ctrl+E, H`, but when you go to options and search for `Type Hierarchy` you should be able to override it:
[image]